# Tengo una lista que contiene 2 clases, pero en el combobox solo quiero que imprima 1 de ellas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

El código que usé es el siguiente:

```
private void ActualizarProducto()

        {
            FrmAltaProducto frm = new FrmAltaProducto();//lo instancio
            frm.ShowDialog();//abro
            cmbProductoVendido.Items.Clear();//limpio el cmb
            cmbProductoVendido.Items.AddRange(clsListaProducto.listaproducto.ToArray());//lo recorro
            cmbProductoVendido.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Además de que usé una clase que contenía una lista que a su vez tenía dos atributos, de los cuales solo necesito uno de ellos, código:

```
public static class clsListaProducto

    //creo una lista de tipo clase donde voy a guardar los productos por precio unitario
    {
        public static List<clsProducto> listaproducto = new List<clsProducto>();
    }


public class clsProducto//es una lista con dos atributos
    {


        public string producto { get; set; }


        public double PrecioUnitario { get; set; }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que sobrescribir el método ToString() de la clase clsProducto y que devuelva el atributo deseado en formato texto.
Ejemplo con producto:

```
  public override string ToString()
        {
            return producto;
        }
```

Ejemplo con PrecioUnitario:

```
    public override string ToString()
        {
            return Convert.ToString(PrecioUnitario);
        }
```